# How to implement authentication and authorization for Spring @MVC 3.0 REST application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been implemented my "skeleton" as Spring @MVC 3.0 REST application. Then can anyone please specify me to, how can I perform authentication and authorization with Spring Security, for my stub (client) applications. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be looking at the spring security tutorial app which is located in the spring security distribution jar.

From the documentation:

> Download the latest Spring Security distribution and unzip the file. After unzipping Spring Security, you'll need to unzip the spring-security-sample-tutorial-3.0.x.war file that you'll find in there, because we need some files that are included within it. After unzipping the war file, you will see a folder called spring-security-samples-tutorial-3.0.x (where "x" is the minor version number).

You can download it [here](http://www.springsource.com/download/community?project=Spring%20Security&version=3.0.5.RELEASE).

Also have a look at the [pet clinic](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html) security tutorial.

A quick security setup for technology exploration purposes should take around 30 minutes.

Comment: Hi Simeon! Many thanks for your valuable feedback, I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot I went through those examples. But I want to know how I implement Spring Security for "Spring @ MVC Rest" application, that mean application provide services with "Spring Controller" methods, clients access them with "Rest" requests, then how I can "Authenticate & Authorize" those clients (that mean whether client should send "User" object with each Rest request etc). one of My Rest controller method is,
// Create a new Car    
@ RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ ResponseBody Car create(@ RequestBody Car car, HttpServletResponse response) { } , Thanks.

Comment: @Channa You can use the method level security. http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html , have a look at section 15.3

Comment: Hi Simeon! Many thanks for your answer, I will looking to that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Simeon! I am bit confusing for how to implement Spring Security for Rest base clients, that mean in this case we can not denote "loing.jsp" etc page configuration in "security.xml" file know :(, then how I configure "AuthenticationEntryPoint" for authenticate Rest base clients (with some Rest URL etc). Thanks