# Current Java webframeworks offering XML or JSON for Android or JavaScript frontend

Tags: java, xml, json, asynchronous

this is my first post on stackoverflow.
I am quite good at Java SE and client side Java Programming, but new to Java web development.
When I search for Java webframeworks, a huge amount of framework are offered, but nothing really seems to fit my needs.
What I actually want is a dumb server and a smart client.
I want the client to ask for certain information and the server to return the requested information in a xml or json format, so that the client itself manages the data.
In most cases the webframeworks render the html pages etc. on the server side, but I just want for example to use AJAX or the android xml parser to get the information and then fill the UI on the clientside.

I am not sure, if Webservices are the right thing for me, because I want to make several async requests to the server.

Or should I simply use servlets, which just return the right xml on request.

A second thing is how to handle the authorization and authentication of the users, which send the request to the webserver.
I do not want to allow everyone to receive the xml or json, which is generated by the server.

In short:
Is there a java based webframework, which can handle authorization and authentication of  users and just returns xml or json to a smart client?

Which java based webframework fits best to my needs?

On the following webpage my aim is described, but unfortunately there is no hint how to implement such a "dumb" server...

> http://seng130.wordpress.com/lectures-2/web-application-architecture/

Comment: you mentioned "android xml" - where does android comes into play?

Comment: I also want to receive xml or json by using the HttpClient and the XmlPullParser in Android. Therefore Android comes into play.

Comment: You can begin with Struts or Spring Framework (yes there is a good learning curve if you have never worked on it). Spring is more of a comprehensive framework with pluggable nature and allows a host of web server tools to be employed. I am sure there are many other frameworks. In addition to other goodies, Spring also supports security modules(authorization and authentication). Spring also supports android. check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737561/how-to-implement-authentication-and-authorization-for-spring-mvc-3-0-rest-appli

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to use multiple frameworks. Spring-Security to handle your url intercept based on authority. Then use Servlet with Spring-MVC to handle the request within the Controller methods. Tutorial here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html You can have those methods return string values of JSON or XML. I would suggest using Jackson to convert your objects to a JSON form on the fly and the javax libraries for XML.

Example of Spring-MVC with Jackson:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

Example with Jersey servlet and Jackson
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/